# mod redirect rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I just want to redirect the URL through the mod rewrite ruls. I have applied this rule excluding (R=301)

Example :
from http:///webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marksandspencer to http:///en/marksandspencer

---

I am using this rules for the mod redirect rules.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/)?$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wcsstore.*$ 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1 [PT,NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/(.*) /$1 [NE,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marksandspencer [PT,NC,L]
```

Comment: I am using this rules for the mod redirect rules.
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp.*$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wcsstore.*$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1 [PT,NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/(.*) /$1 [NE,L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marksandspencer [PT,NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're trying to do, but if you're using Apache 2.0 or higher, the leading slash is stripped off of URI's when matching is done within a `RewriteRule`. Also, you have a rule that looks like you're adding a `/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/` to the beginning of a URI, then the very next rule it looks like you are removing it. This will probably cause a loop.

Taking a wild guess at what you are trying to do, I think you need to add a condition to the 2nd rule, and remove the leading slashes:

```
# internally rewrite URI by appending "/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/" to the front
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/)?$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wcsstore.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1 [PT,NC,L,QSA] 

# if a request is made with "/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/" in it, redirect to a URI with it stripped
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET/POST)\ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/
RewriteRule ^webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marksandspencer [PT,NC,L]
```

Comment: The issue is if I use the Redirect flag R=301 then the post request is not working. But I need the both the POST and GET request. So ow can I do this.
RewriteRule ^/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/(.*) /$1 [R=301,E,L,QSA]

Comment: RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/)?$ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/webapp.*$ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wcsstore.*$ RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/$1 [PT,NC,L,QSA] RewriteRule ^/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/(.*) /$1 [R=301,NE,L,QSA] RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marksandspencer [PT,NC,L] 
Now the URL making from the  http:///webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marksandspencer to http:///en/marksandspencer. 

If I use this rules then it is working fine with get request but not with the post request. So How can I achive for both.

Comment: You can't redirect a POST request like that.